# Weinre server no target for debugging webview

Tags: webview, weinre

I'm trying to debug a webview on my phone using the weinre server. It shows up as a client but not as a target. I know that 4.4 and above have chrome debugging but I need to debug in 4.3
I've tried changing the localhost to the my ip address but it doesn't work. Any ideas as to why the target is not showing up?
I've attached a screenshot for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server (running on your windows computer?) needs to be visible to your (android?) phone.  Can you browse to the weinre server on your windows computer from your android phone - just to test that you have connectivity there?

You could also try using a public weinre server, such as: http://weinre.mybluemix.net/

Also possible there is an error in your HTML or other JS somewhere that is preventing the weinre script from running.  You could try running on a 4.4 device and use a real debugger to see if you can figure out why it won't work on your 4.3 device.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Left out the os details. Im using windows and an android phone running 4.3. I can't seem to access the server from my phone. I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in chrome mobile

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` sounds like your windows machine has a firewall blocking incoming connections to your weinre server (probably either port 8080 or 8081).  Run Windows Firewall and add a rule to allow connections over the port number you're running the weinre server on.